# Unable to find other entity-type in Apache Atlas . Only Showing hdfs_path

Tags: apache-atlas

Hi I am new to Apache Atlas . And I am facing a problem.
I want to create a hive_table entity type manually but in Entity type drop downs its showing only "hdfs_path"
Can anyone let me know how I can use a custom entity type in apache Atlas.
And can anyone provide me a good documentation part or tutorial apart form Apche Atlas site.

[Here is the photo where I want to add a new entity type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvAZa.png)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: you need to apply the following setting to atlas-application.properties, and restart:

```
atlas.ui.editable.entity.types=<your entity types>
```

Note that `<your entity types>` can be a comma-separated list, like `hdfs_path,kafka_topic` or, to just allow *all* Types to be created and edited via the UI, use a star `*`.

I guess the reason for this restrictive default is because metadata in Atlas is normally synchronised from other systems using hooks and bridges. So in order to keep the metadata "consistent" (i.e. prevent the risk of people creating metadata entries in Atlas which do not correspond to actual data assets existing in the referenced systems), by default editing Entity Types via the UI is locked down.

Reference: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ATLAS-3237

Answer (score 0):

hive_table entity should be synced using import scripts.

"hdfs_path" is not synced automatically unless they belong to lineage, hence the option to create them manually.

However, if you want to create them manually, please check the following link, which has the steps:-

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-create-hive-table-entity-in-Apache-atlas-using-REST/td-p/173644

Comment: Thanks .But can you explain me why different entity type does not shows up in the dropdown when I try to create a new entity by clicking on create entity from GUI.?

Comment: @SuryaPrakashGupta, atlas has hooks that import entities from hive and hbase.
Let's say you have hive db called "test", it should be pop up automatically, if hooks are configured properly.
This can not be done with hdfs as it may have millions of files, so for hdfs you can see form ui to create hdfs paths but not others entity types. Using hokks is always good option that creating them manually.